# owl.carousel vue.js component not rendering in lavarel application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, owl-carousel, v-for

I've been hunting and trying for the last handful of days but with no success.

I am trying to render a list of quotes to be displayed as a carousal on a login page.

I need to pull a list of quotes from a database which i have done. I then need to loop through the quotes and display them in the owl.carousel.

If i manually add the div.elements, it renders without a problem. when i add the element in a v-for loop, it does not display. Can someone please advise or guide me into the correct direction?

```
<template>

<carousel class="crsl" :autoplay="true" :nav="false" :items="1">

    <div v-for="(item, index) in quotes" :key="item.id" v-text="item.quote"></div>

</carousel>
```

```
import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel';

export default {

    components: { carousel },

    mounted() {

        console.log('Component mounted.')

        axios.post('api/quotes', {})
            .then(response => {
                this.quotes = response.data;
            });
    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            quotes: null,
        }
    },

}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser’s console?

Comment: Just the normal parse soureMap warnings, other than that no errors. - @DelenaMalan

Comment: https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/issues/16

Seem to have found a solution on this thread

Comment: Nice find. You're welcome to post an answer to your own question if you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution here
https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/issues/16

My final code is as follows

```
<template>

<div v-if="quotes.length > 0">
    <carousel :items="1" :autoplay="true" :nav="false" :dots="false">

        <div v-for="(item, index) in quotes">

            <div v-text="item.quote"></div>

        </div>

    </carousel>
</div>
```

```
<script>

import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel';

export default {

    components: { carousel },

    data() {
        return {
            quotes: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.post('/api/quotes')
            .then(resp => {
                this.quotes = resp.data;
            });
    },
}
```